# Does Arrow Functions in JS also inherit the Function() prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Given the risk of prototype-pollution in JavaScript,

In case I can't freeze/seal the built-in `Function()'s` prototype, or some of it's parents in the prototype-chain (eg `Object()`'s),

can I use arrow-functions, in order to guarantee it's execution/calls to be straight-forward, without the chance for `Proxy()`'ies, side-effects of hooks, or any other kind of manipulation possible due to pollution of regular functions?

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable) (which was marked as a forwarding answer to a duplicated question to mine, that has no answer) I can't understand if it's guaranteed that arrow-functions are not prototyped, by standard or by de-facto implementations.

In [Mozilla's MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), I found no mentions to a prototype of Arrow-Functions.

My goal is to restrict some critical logic, to make its execution safe from any possible modification, differing, injected side-effects, monitoring, wrapping, triggering of events, and more. * (And maybe even debugging, if possible, but it's maybe for another question).

Comment: What do you mean by "straight-forward"? Do you have any code that demonstrates an issue?

Comment: A `Proxy` doesn't change the behaviour of the original object. Similarly, functions do not depend on any of their properties, unless the function's body itself references them; there are no hooks that execute automatically, unless the function explicitly calls them. The "pollution" danger is in replacing methods that a function depends on, not in modifying the function object itself. For example, if `foo` calls `Math.sin`, no modification to `foo` properties will affect it; but if you replace `Math.sin` with e.g. `Math.sin = function(x) { return 42 }`, that will mess it up.

Comment: "*in order to guarantee it's execution/calls to be straight-forward, without the change for `Proxy()'its, side-effects of hooks, or any other kind of manipulation possible due to pollution of regular functions?*" - this does not make sense. Regular functions are not subject to prototype pollution any more or less than arrow functions. Just call them, there is no way a polluted prototype can intercept that.

Comment: @Amadan it was a typo. I mean "chance for proxies" and not "changes of proxies", sorry, fixed

Comment: @Bergi why not? I can't modify the Function object in some environments or hosts? Or even the inner Object one?

Comment: @Cocktail Basically see Adaman's reasoning. You cannot mutate what a function does. And modifying/overwriting `Function` or `Function.prototype` does not at all affect function calls. It just doesn't matter. What matter is if someone replaces the functions in the variables/properties that you are calling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does and it's easy to check:

```js
const boo = () => {};

function hoo() {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(boo) === Object.getPrototypeOf(hoo)); // true
```

Comment: Wow that's crazy